# iOS Back button on centre of window using Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to place a back button at centre of window. I am able to achieve the same using image view. However navigation to previous windows except for the very last are failing.

Lets say I have traversed three windows A->B->C. From window 'C' the button takes me to window 'B'. But from window 'B' click of same button evokes no response (ideally it should have taken me to window 'A')

The code I have used are as following

```
{
    var imgView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        top:'50%',
        left : 0,
        image : "icons/back.png"
    });


    imgView.addEventListener('click', function(){
        self.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the error you getting?

Comment: No error. Lets say I have traversed three windows A->B->C. From window 'C' the button takes me to window 'B'. But from window 'B' click of same button evokes no response (ideally it should have taken me to window 'A')

Comment: please add the above comment with your code so that your question will be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the above line in your each file which containing the new window, since you're opening new windows using url method.

```
var currentWindow = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
```

Then close the window as follows

```
imgView.addEventListener('click', function(){
    currentWindow.close();
});
```

This will close the current window, since [currentWindow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow) represents the active window

I'll add the working Example :

**app.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var back = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'To win1 ',
    width   : '70%'
});

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url : 'win1.js',
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        layout  : 'vertical'
    });
    win1.open();
});
win.add(back);
win.open();
```

**win1.js**

```
var self = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var back = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Back to home',
    top     : 20,
    width   : '70%'
});

var next = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'To win2',
    top     : 20,
    width   : '70%'
});

self.add(back);
self.add(next);

back.addEventListener('click',function(){
    self.close();
});

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url : 'win2.js',
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        layout      : 'vertical'
    });
    win2.open();
});
```

**win2.js**

```
var self = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var back = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Back to win1',
    top     : 20,
    width   : '70%'
});

self.add(back);

back.addEventListener('click',function(){
    self.close();
});
```

Comment: I tried that. even though I created window with url parameter, handle to current window remains undefined.

Comment: How you opening the new window?

Comment: self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  url:'custom.js',
  backgroundColor:'#ffffff', 
  
 });

Comment: @prasadkatankot: I've done a sample application to fix your issue and I found that it's working fine, I've added the working example also :)